# Change Putty Session's Title Text in Windows 7 Command Line

Tags: windows, cmd, putty

I am trying to open a putty session from windows command line. I need to change the Title text that will appear in its title bar.

I'm using the command:

```
putty.exe --ssh serverName -l myName -pw password
```

In the title bar it displays,

```
myName@serverName:~
```

But I need to change the title text as we can do using putty GUI, 
    putty --> Window --> Behaviour --> Window Title.

I need a command line option for this setting something like,

```
putty.exe --ssh serverName -l myName -pw passwor **-title myTitle**
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is a batch file command called `title` that changes the text in the title bar.
Use this on the line before starting `putty`

```
title myTitle
```

Comment: He is asking how to change the Putty title, not the batch window title. I need the same BTW. Change the batch title does not fits for me :(